# How do I find files that are created/modified/accessed before reboot?

Tags: bash, tmp, uptime

On a remote system (that I am not an administrator of) I have configured an alternative `TMPDIR` in my `.profile (because the system default has very limited space).

This alternative `TMPDIR` is of course not cleaned on reboot. That's why I want to periodically (or on logon) wipe the directory. However, I may be logged in several times with long running scripts when I'm not logged in, so actually `rm`ing the entire contents is not an option.

Is there a way (preferably in `bash`, but the usual tools are available) to find files in a specific directory that are older than the most recent reboot, as to clean my `TMPDIR`?

Comment: You can use `uptime -s` to get the time of last boot, then `find` to list files which have an mtime older than that.

Comment: Can you add an @reboot cron job?

Comment: Cron is disabled for my user account

Answer (score 2):

Same as answered by Thomas, but with an easier way to find boot time using btime field of /proc/stat

```
$ DT=$(awk '$1 ~ /btime/ { print "print scalar localtime("$2")" }' /proc/stat|perl)
$ echo $DT
Fri Nov 13 15:04:28 2015
$ last reboot|head -1
reboot   system boot  3.16.0-4-amd64   Fri Nov 13 15:04 - 22:53 (5+07:49)  
$ touch -d "$DT" /tmp/foo
```

and use find with -newer option

Comment: Can you please explain why you are piping awk to perl without doing anything?

Comment: btime in /proc/stat is time since epoch. Using awk to print  perl code using that time and finally feeding it to perl

Comment: Nice explanation. I have posted my final solution below, mostly based on yours.

Answer (score 1):

This simple one-liner might help to delete all files and directories in `TMPDIR` modified before last reboot:

```bash
$ find $TMPDIR -mindepth 1 -depth -not -newermt "$(uptime -s)" -delete
```

Your machine has to support `uptime -s` and the `find` option `-newerXY` for this to work.

Here `-newermt` is a special form of `-newerXY` and looks for files and directories (m)odified after the reference (t)imestamp, which in this case is the output of `uptime -s`.

See the [`find` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) for details about `-newerXY`.

Using `-not` we reverse `-newermt`  to find files that were modified *before* or exactly at time of the last reboot and not after it.

`-depth` cares for handling directory contents before the directory itself (important for recursive deletion).

`-mindepth 1` ensures, that the `TMPDIR` directory itself is kept.

If you only want to *list* the respective files (insteasd of removing them), just remove `-delete`.

If you want to list *and* delete just append `-printf "%p\n" -delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Noting the comment, `uptime -s` is fairly recent (appearing in Linux-specific code at the [end of 2012](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/commit/a705fdcb15c0515d512d54df43d3738b708ead65)).

A little more portable might be to use the output of `last`, which lists system boot timestamps, e.g.,

```
tom      pts/0        michener.jexium- Wed Nov 18 17:00   still logged in
reboot   system boot  3.2.0-4-amd64    Wed Nov 18 16:47 - 20:36  (03:49)
tom      pts/0        michener.jexium- Wed Nov 18 04:12 - down   (01:21)
reboot   system boot  3.2.0-4-amd64    Wed Nov 18 04:04 - 05:33  (01:29)
tom      pts/0        michener.jexium- Tue Nov 17 17:03 - down   (04:24)
```

and (with grep or awk) getting the timestamp of the most recent "reboot" line, and using *that* as an argument to `touch`, e.g.,

```
LAST=$(last | grep -E '^reboot ' | sed -e 's/^.\{39\}//' -e 's/\(.\{16\}\).*/\1/' | head -n 1)
```

That would let you use the `-newer` option of [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), and work for reboot-times in fractions of a day:

```
FILE=/tmp/foo
touch -d "$LAST" $FILE
find $MY_TMPDIR ! -newer $FILE -exec echo rm -rf {} \;
```

The weak part of this, of course, is knowing the format of [`last`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/last.1.html) output (but there is no standard for *that*).

Comment: This will remove files that are _newer_ than the last reboot, not _older._ And it will not remove directories.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer provided by VenkatC, I ended up using the following script to clean my tmp folder.

```
if [ -d $tmpdir ] || mkdir -p $tmpdir
then
    chmod 700 $tmpdir
    export TMPDIR="$tmpdir"

    DT=$(awk '$1 ~ /btime/ { print "print scalar localtime("$2")" }' /proc/stat|perl)
    touch -d "$DT" "$TMPDIR"

    find "$TMPDIR" -mindepth 1 -not -newer "$TMPDIR" -delete
fi
```

Comment: I am not sure it is a good idea to test the date of $TMPDIR. Would deleting files in $TMPDIR not change the date of $TMPDIR?

Comment: Interesting observation. However, in the event that anything would be deleted, everything should be deleted, so it does not matter too much.

Comment: Thinking twice, I don't think "find" is checking the date of the reference at each comparison.

Comment: You can remove `[ -d $tmpdir ] || `.  `mkdir -p dir` returns true if dir exists.  The avoidance of calling an external process is not worth the extra verbage in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that parses the output of `uptime`, calculates the total minutes since boot, and finds files modified greater than that many minutes ago.  I tested this on FreeBSD 10.2, Debian Jessie 8, and Ubuntu Trusty 14.04.  I don't know about the `uptime` output format on other systems.

The heart of this is the `awk` script in the `uptime_minutes` function, which could be placed into a command file on it's own for use in other `find` commands and situations where you need to know the number of minutes of uptime, probably accurate to within 1 minute.

Save this in a file and execute with `sh filename directory ...` where `filename` is the name you chose for the script, and `directory` is the directory, one or more, that you want to search:

```
    #!/bin/sh

    uptime_minutes() {
        uptime |
        awk '
            {
                for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
                    if ($i == "up") {
                        split($(i+3), hhmm, "[:,]")
                        print ($(i+1) * 24 * 60) + (hhmm[1] * 60) + hhmm[2]
                        exit
                    }
                }
            }
        '
    }
    find "${@:?}" -mmin +$(uptime_minutes) # -exec rm {} \;
```

The `"${@:?}"` just prints and error if you don't supply any directory arguments.

The file removal code is commented out on the end.  Just remove the `#` if you want to really remove the files instead of print their names.